# CSS styling for multi-leveled hovering

Tags: html, css

I have most of the CSS down, except for this last little part... my final child, when its corresponding parent is hovered appears on the top line as opposed to being on the same line...

It may have something to do with this line of code, but I'm not sure...
Here is my fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/H9CTe/7/

```
#ipc_cases ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/H9CTe/9/

Just add `position: relative;` to `#ipc_cases li`. This will make `top: 0` align with its parent element.

Comment: Also, putting in `#ipc_cases li { top: -1px; }` will make them align properly.

Comment: Awesome... so I edited it up a little bit, how can I fix the borders from overlapping? http://jsfiddle.net/H9CTe/12/